# Fully resolve ng-click function before ng-href?

Tags: angularjs

I've been having a problem, and the simplest solution in my mind is to get what is described in my title to work; a full resolution of a function before the href navigation. Is this possible?

More info - I'm trying to submit form data and open an sms with the same button. Opening the sms works without the ng-click, but once I try to execute a function, only the function is resolved.

Comment: The bound click function/event *will* complete execution before the browser default behavior ('href' or 'submit') triggers. There is a piece of the puzzle missing; and it probably has many answers that can be found by searching for "async".

Answer (score 1):

You could navigate to the new page from the controller instead of the ng-click. This way you can way for your promise to resolve before redirecting to the new page using [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

```
<a href="" ng-click="myFunc()">Link</a>
```

Your controller

```
$scope.myFunc = function() {
  // sample promise
  $http.get().then(resp) {
    // once promise is resolved, navigate to new page
    $location.path('path/to/sms')
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using $location.path('sms:&body=test') and a few variations of that to no avail.

Comment: @SpencerF. this seems to be an issue with how you're referencing your path. What is the path to the sms page? (when you're on the page, what does the url say?)

Comment: I'm confused by this. The link opens up the sms app for the user with a precomposed text. What do you mean by what is the path?